# ios - Program with block executed out of order?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I'm trying to get an array of urls from my backend.

I use `AFNetworking` and I have a `HTTPUtil` class implemented as `singleton` to handle my requests.

**HTTPUtil.m**

```
#import "HTTPUtil.h"

@implementation HTTPUtil

+(instancetype)sharedInstance{
    NSLog(@"sharedInstance");    //to check the order
    static HTTPUtil* manager;
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        manager = [[HTTPUtil alloc] init];
    });
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    return manager;
}

-(void)getImageArrayFromURL:(NSString *)url success:(void(^)(NSArray* array))success failure:(void(^)(NSError* error))failure{
    NSLog(@"getting...");    //to check the order
    [self GET:url parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask* task, id response){
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", response);
        NSString* imgStr = [[response objectForKey:kResponseDataKey] objectForKey:@"img"];

        //convert nsstring to nsarray
        NSArray* array = [StringUtil arrayFromString:imgStr];

        //construct urls
        NSMutableArray* ret = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSMutableString* url;
        for (NSString* rawStr in array) {
            url = [NSMutableString stringWithString:kUrlBase];
            [url appendString:[rawStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"+"]];
            [ret addObject:url];
        }
        success(ret);
    }failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask* task, NSError* error){
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        failure(error);
    }];
}
```

In my view controller, I call the method to fetch the array.

```
    _vCycleScrollView = [SDCycleScrollView cycleScrollViewWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) delegate:self placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked"]];
    NSMutableString* url = [NSMutableString stringWithString:kUrlBase];
    [url appendString:@"activityImgArray"];
//
     __block NSArray* imgarr;
    [[HTTPUtil sharedInstance] getImageArrayFromURL:url success:^(NSArray* array){
        imgarr = [NSArray arrayWithArray:array];
    }failure:^(NSError* error){
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }];
    NSLog(@"adding...");
    _vCycleScrollView.imageURLStringsGroup = imgarr;

[self.view addSubview:_vCycleScrollView];
[_vCycleScrollView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker* make){
    make.top.equalTo(self.view);
    make.left.equalTo(self.view);
    make.right.equalTo(self.view);
    make.height.mas_equalTo(180);
    make.width.equalTo(self.view.mas_width);
}];
```

In the console, I got

```
2016-05-20 14:41:19.411 SCUxCHG[10470:4909076] sharedInstance
2016-05-20 14:41:19.415 SCUxCHG[10470:4909076] getting...
2016-05-20 14:41:19.417 SCUxCHG[10470:4909076] adding...
2016-05-20 14:41:19.591 SCUxCHG[10470:4909076] 
Response: {
    data =     {
        img = "[activity/test1, acti/1]";
    };
    message = success;
    result = 0;
}
```

I thought `imgArr` **should be assigned in the `success` block and it shouldn't be `nil` when I assign it to `_vCycleScrollView.imageURLStringsGroup`.**

However, I can tell from the output in the console that the `HTTP` request is sent after `NSLog(@"adding...");` and that leads to the fact that `imgArr` is still `nil` when `_vCycleScrollView.imageURLStringsGroup = imgarr;` is executed.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes below code is in block so this will continue in background

```
[[HTTPUtil sharedInstance] getImageArrayFromURL:url success:^(NSArray* array){
    imgarr = [NSArray arrayWithArray:array];
}failure:^(NSError* error){
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}];
```

solution - You should add **_vCycleScrollView.imageURLStringsGroup = imgarr;** inside of success block because you d0 not know when it will completed Or there is another way you should not call in block or should not create block.

Comment: If I add `_vCycleScrollView.imageURLStringsGroup = imgarr;` into the block, is it possible that `_vCycleScrollView` is initiated incorrectly? Because right below ``_vCycleScrollView.imageURLStringsGroup = imgarr;` I have `[self.view addSubview:_vCycleScrollView];`. You can see in my EDIT.

Comment: Can you check imaArr count and then add scrollview on view.Is this fine for you,Because with nil data there is no use of show scrollview on view.

Comment: If answer is helpful for you please up the acceptance

Answer (score 1):

Try bellow:

```
 __block NSArray* imgarr;
[[HTTPUtil sharedInstance] getImageArrayFromURL:url success:^(NSArray* array){
    imgarr = [NSArray arrayWithArray:array];
    NSLog(@"adding...");
    _vCycleScrollView.imageURLStringsGroup = imgarr;
}failure:^(NSError* error){
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}];
```

The completion block is executed once data is fetched. 
In your case code continues to execute after the completion block is set but data hasn't been fetched yet, that's why imgarr is nil.

Comment: Oh, I was too late

Answer (score 0):

That's the whole idea: That blocks are executed out of order. The trick is that you don't *wait* for a block to finish. Instead, the block finishes and then it does what is needed. The code in your viewcontroller isn't going to work, can't work, and we don't want it to work. Instead, the callback block deposits the image somewhere, and then tells the tableview to reload the row.